# Add/prepend a GET variable name using redirects in htaccess (to fix broken URL)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a php script that relies on a $_GET variable called "serial." Normally the URL would look like this:
http://www.example.com/script.php?serial=XXXXXX

However, the person making the QR codes thought that the URL was too long and has already finished making QR codes that point to this URL:
http://www.example.com/script.php?XXXXXX

The part they left out was the "serial=", so PHP can't $_GET the variable anymore.

Is it possible to redirect using .htaccess to add the "serial=" back in?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just check if serial is specified? If not, you could use a default value.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no default value. Check out Jon Lin's answer - it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^serial=
RewriteRule ^script\.php$ /script.php?serial=%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

If you want to redirect the browser, add a `R` to the inside of the square brackets so that it looks like `[L,R]`.